# jQuery autocomplete - automatic open on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Thanks for the help in advance!

I've been trying to create a small input that show some autocomplete option when the user focus the input. I was able to to this by using this:

```
    .bind('focus', function(){ $(this).autocomplete("search")
```

But, after researching a little more I had to change the autoselect to be a request/response to be able to display the selected value on another div. After I did this, i can't make the .bind to work to show the menu automatically when you focus on the input.

Here's the code:

```
$(".languageinput").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {

        var availableTags = [];
        var availableTags = [
        "EN",
        "DE",
        "ES",
        "FR",
        "ID",
        "IT",
        "JA",
        "KR",
        "PT",
        "RU",
        "TH",
        "VN",
        "ZH",
        ];

        response(availableTags);
        return;


        },

        select: function (e, ui) {

            $('.utm_campaign').empty();$('.utm_campaign').html($(".languageinput").val())
        },

        change: function (e, ui) {

            $('.utm_campaign').empty();$('.utm_campaign').html($(".languageinput").val())
        }   
    })
;
```

Comment: RIP RIP RIP RIP

Comment: Here's the answer for my own question:  $(".languageinput").on("focus", function () {$(this).autocomplete("search", "");});